# Execute any file as powershell script

Tags: powershell

I encountered a challenge that I failed to resolve the way I wanted it to do.

I got a file that contains a powershell script, but that file does not have the extension assigned to powershell. The question is: **How can I execute a powershell in a script file with the wrong file extension (or none)?**

`Invoke-Expression` does not seem to work because it always executes the default action assigned to the file type. If I give that cmdlet a `*.txt` file the editor pops open.

I know that I can resolve that by renaming the script file or naming it properly in the first place. This is what I ended up doing.

Still I wonder if it is possible to execute a file as a script with the wrong file extension without modifying, renaming or coping the file. And if it is not working… why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell is designed such that executing or dot sourcing a file requires a `.ps1` extension, and Powershell.exe will refuse to run any file that doesn't have that extension.

One way to invoke Powershell code from a non-ps1 file is to launch Powershell.exe using STDIN, and pipe your script to it.  This requires a new shell, so is not very good for launching scripts from within an existing scripting environment.

```
Powershell.exe - < thescript.txt
```

Another way is to create a temporary `.ps1` file and execute that.  This has the advantage of using the current scripting environment, but requires a temporary file.

```
Copy-Item -Path '.\thescript.txt' -Dest '.\temp.ps1'
. .\temp.ps1
del .\temp.ps1
```

In my opinion, the file extension restriction is silly, but that's how it was designed.  Apocryphally, this is for security reasons, but I can find no citation to back it up.

Comment: As an alternative you could also just append the extension `.ps1` to the filename: `Get-Item '.\thescript.txt' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name + '.ps1' }`. It can be renamed back using the `BaseName` property.

Answer (score 1):

Or you use `Get-Content` to read the file and then invoke that with `Invoke-Expression` or `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock`.

Comment: Unfortunate you didn't actually give examples.

Comment: That's because this is an extemely trivial thing to do.  if you follow a basic Powershell course you'll learn how to do this